# What will be the hostname for ec2 instance phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have setup an instance and now I want to connect my website with database. What would be the hostname If I want to connect to phpmyadmin. Will hostname be `localhost`?.I am using a following code:-

```
class Database{

// specify your own database credentials
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "PHPLearning";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
public $conn;

// get the database connection
public function getConnection(){

    $this->conn = null;

    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```

}

Comment: This will depend on how your instance is set up. localhost is a likely default assuming you have mysql running on the same machine.

Comment: You will get the hostname from your AWS console. It will either be the public URL for the EC2 instance or the URL for the ELB, if you're using one.

Comment: @Gavin. Yes, I have setup phpmyadmin for the same machine and I want to connect with the database of the same machine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I am not using ELB. So, public URL would be the IPV4 of the machine?

Comment: No, it will be the public URL of the EC2 instance.

Comment: please check the documentation from aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Answer (score -1):

your code is correct. but it not work then change host from localhost to **127.0.0.1**